# Run a service on all nodes with fleet in coreos

Tags: service-discovery, coreos

I'm looking for a way to run a single fleet service on all nodes in my coreos cluster.
I'm stuck with having to specify x number of services but I want some services to run as default on all the nodes in my container. 
Even if I add a new node to the cluster, I want the service to be running on the new node as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fleet 0.8 contains global units. fleet 0.8 is currently shipping in CoreOS 435.0.0, which is currently available in the alpha channel.

https://coreos.com/releases/

https://github.com/coreos/fleet/blob/master/Documentation/unit-files-and-scheduling.md#fleet-specific-options